# Visual Studio - Printing "X" with Coordinates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need your help with the coordinates. What I would like to happen is to print an "X" after the given coordinates. Example: The given coordinates for x-axis is 2 and y-axis is 2

[image]

the output will be:

[image]

So basically, 2 "#" on the top and 2 "#" on the left, then it will print the letter "X"

```
Dim d As String = ""

For i = 0 To NumericUpDownX.Value
            For j = 0 To NumericUpDownY.Value
                d = d & "#"
            Next
            d = d & vbNewLine
Next
output.Text = d
```

I was able to print the # but I can't seem to figure out how to put the "X" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this with the [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) constructor and [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_):

```
Dim d As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For y = 0 To NumericUpDownY.Value
    If y < NumericUpDownY.Value Then
        d.AppendLine(New String("#", NumericUpDownX.Value + 1))
    Else
        d.AppendLine("X".PadLeft(NumericUpDownX.Value + 1, "#"))
    End If
Next
output.Text = d.ToString
```

If you want something more inline with what you were originally doing, then:

```
Dim d As String = ""
For y = 0 To NumericUpDownY.Value
    For x = 0 To NumericUpDownX.Value
        If y = NumericUpDownY.Value AndAlso x = NumericUpDownX.Value Then
            d = d & "X"
        Else
            d = d & "#"
        End If
    Next
    d = d & vbCrLf
Next
output.Text = d
```